# UICollectionView change cell data when scrolled in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Selection of cells gets changed when UICollectionView scrolled. Below is what i am doing, please check the code mentioned below. I select cells in section 0 which have multiple cells and section 1 which have only one cell. So, on selection of section 1 cell all selections made in section 0 will gets clear. This functionality is working but on scroll selection gets changes.

```
func initUI()
{
   self.collectionViewBrands!.registerClass(SignupStep3CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "SignupStep3CollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)
    self.collectionViewBrands.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.collectionViewBrands.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
     return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0
    {
        return self.arrItems.count
    }
    else
    {
        return 1
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if section == 1
    {
        let flowLayout = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout)
        let cellSpacing = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        let cellWidth = flowLayout.itemSize.width
        let cellCount = CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section))

        let totalCellWidth = cellWidth * cellCount
        let totalSpacingWidth = cellSpacing * (cellCount - 1)

        let leftInset = (self.collectionViewBrands.frame.size.width - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2;
        let rightInset = leftInset

        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)
    }
    else
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 28, 0)
    }
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SignupStep3CollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.lblNone.hidden = true
        cell.imgBrands.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imgBrands.image = UIImage(named: "logo_sample")
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imgBrands.image = UIImage(named: "")
        cell.lblNone.hidden = false
        cell.lblNone.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.lblNone.text = "None"
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SignupStep3CollectionViewCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 234.0/255.0, blue: 219.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2
    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
          self.arrSelectedItems.addObject(self.arrItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))

        let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 1)
        self.collectionViewBrands.reloadSections(indexSet)
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 0)
        self.arrSelectedItems.removeAllObjects()
        self.collectionViewBrands.reloadSections(indexSet)
    }
}
```

Please guide what is wrong above. And feel free to ask if any thing not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that due to the cell reusing mechanism of `UICollectionView`, you are not guaranteed that you'll get the same cell instance at a given index path, thus the configuration you made in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` might get lost.

You can solve the problem by configuring the cell selection look&feel in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
let cellIsSelected: Bool = cell.selected

if cellIsSelected {
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 234.0/255.0, blue: 219.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
} else {
    // set the default layer values, to make sure that a dequeued cell that was marked as selected at the time it was queued resets its look&feel 
}
```